# Pass AltGr+i through SSH client

Tags: ssh, vim, putty

I use several Vim shortcuts like <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, etc. When I connect to a Linux machine via SSH using PuTTY, these keystrokes are not passed to `vim` on the remote host. Polish diacritics like `ą` (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>), `ż` (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>), `ó` (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) are passed correctly.

Is there a way to make my shortcuts also work? I could not find any settings that would enable them.

I'm using PuTTY but I may accept a solution that involves another SSH client for Windows, free of such an issue (I have checked MobaXterm, it is not).

Comment: [‘Control-Alt is different from AltGr’](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/config-ctrlalt.html)

Comment: It is already checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution I needed.
Basically, the <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, etc. keystrokes on Windows produce different codes than on Linux. The solution is to modify the codes produced by the keystrokes. I used [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for that purpose. Having installed AutoHotkey, I created a script `my_win_autohotkey.ahk`:

```
<^>!i::SendInput {raw}→
<^>!b::SendInput {raw}”
<^>!q::SendInput {raw}π
<^>!f::SendInput {raw}æ
<^>!t::SendInput {raw}ß
<^>!0::SendInput {raw}»
<^>!r::SendInput {raw}©
```

and executed it. This made <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> produce `→`, and so on, just like on Linux. I have also added the script to Startup (`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder on Windows 10), so there is no need to run it manually after the system restart. Now, my Vim shortcuts work via PuTTy too :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass "key combinations" through ssh, the only thing you can pass through ssh are characters. Polish diacritics are converted to the correct (unicode) character on your local side, so they work.

If you configure your local side to generate proper character sequences (maybe ESC sequences) for the key codes, and configure your vim on the remote side to accept these sequences, then you can also pass those via ssh.

Comment: Actually these key combinations produce proper (?) characters (`AltGr+i` - `→`, `AltGr+q` - `π`, `AltGr+b` - `”`) and my vim mappings use exactly those characters.

Comment: Then the obvious first step is to see (1) if they arrive on the remote host (2) if they get converted in the process to something else. `echo`, `cat` and `hexdump` on the shell should be enough to test this, unless the shell and vim have a different character conversion layer for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm... how can I do this?
None of these (`→`, `π`, `”`) characters can be written into a command line via putty.

Comment: Ah, actually I can't put these symbols anywhere in Windows with these shortcuts. I'll take a look at character sets and keyboards in Windows.